# TWRP only allows flashing into either the Boot or Recovery partitions

Tags: twrp, samsung-galaxy-j7, treble

I'm trying to flash a [Pixel Experience GSI](https://forum.xda-developers.com/project-treble/trebleenabled-device-development/9-0-pixelexperience-p-t3833294) onto my 2017 Samsung (SM-J730G) using [TWRP](https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-j7-2017/development/j730f-fm-g-gm-x-samsung-galaxy-j7-pro-t3835629). In order to do so, I need to flash the GSI's `system.img` into my device's System partition. However, my TWRP only allowed me to flash into either the Boot or Recovery partitions. The other options I see in other phones (System, Vendor, Preload, etc.) are nowhere to be found.

Comment: This sounds very device/ROM specific as this not the "normal" way to install a ROM image. I would highly recommend posting in the thread you linked above for assistance as it appears to be quite active. That said, this is Treble ROM and your device does not appear to be Treble compatible.

Comment: My device just got unofficial Treble support. This resolves my issue.